# DataBinding in CellEditDataTemplate not working when use ElementName

Tags: wpf

I have tried to update ItemSource of RadComboBox using ElementName property in Binding but when I use RelativeSource it is working as expected.

What is the difference.Can anyone please tell me.

```
 <telerik:RadGridView   Name="DesiredCapabilitiesGrid" RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed" AllowDrop="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True ShowGroupPanel="False" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"ItemsSource="{Binding DesiredCapabilities,Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                           GroupRenderMode="Flat" NewRowPosition="Bottom" Loaded="DesiredCapabilitiesGrid_Loaded">                            
                        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Property Names" Width="2*" IsSortable="True" DataMemberBinding="{Binding DesiredCapabilityName}">
                                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.ConsiderDesiredCapabilites,ElementName="DesiredCapabilitiesGrid"}" IsEditable="True"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>                                        
                                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>

                        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no element named `DesiredCapabilitiesGrid` in the same [namescope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-xaml-namescopes) as the `RadComboBox` in the `CellEditTemplate`. That's why the binding fails.

The `RadComboBox` is added to the visual tree and has visual ancestors though. That's why setting a `RelativeSource` work. Please refer to the link for more information about namescopes.